# How to find multiple property in an object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I have been working on this challenge form FCC
here is the
[Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/wherefore-art-thou)

this is the challenge

> Make a function that looks through an array of objects (first
> argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching name
> and value pairs (second argument). Each name and value pair of the
> source object has to be present in the object from the collection if
> it is to be included in the returned array.
>
> For example, if the first argument is `[{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }],` and the second argument is `{ last: "Capulet" },`
> then you must return the third object from the array (the first
> argument), because it contains the name and its value, that was passed
> on as the second argument.

this is my code so far

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  let propFinder = Object.keys(source);

  // Only change code below this line
collection.map(x=>{

if(x[propFinder] ===  source[propFinder]){
    arr.push(x)
 }

})

  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}


// this one does not match
whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 });
// expected output { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]

// but this this one match

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }) 

// expected output [{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }]
```

Comment: `collection.map(...)` if you don't use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: Have a look at `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.every()`